# How to generate EXE using JSmooth that will run JVM in the same process as the executable?

Tags: process, jsmooth

I am using JSmooth to generate EXE for my Java application. If I run the executable as administrator, the Java process runs within the same process as the executable. Otherwise it spawns a new javaw process. I would like for the java process to always run in the same process as the executable.

How can I make the executable to not spawn new process for javaw?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found the answer to this as I begun using **JSmooth** but if you look under "**Skeleton**" and select "**Windowed Wrapper**", you will see the option to "**Launch java app in the exe process**" checkbox.  I believe this is what you're looking for.